# What causes my dog to regularly "meet" me coming up the stairs, walk past me going down and then circle back and follow me up

Tags: dogs, training, adoption

What causes my dog to regularly "meet" me coming up the stairs, walk past me going down and then circle back and follow me back up. And the same thing when I go downstairs. If she is already downstairs she will go upstairs, passing me by, circle back and follow me down. If I stand still, she will stand still too.

A little background. She is a ten pound 2 year old rescue and previously lived with a pack of 8 other small poodle-ish dogs like her, none of them socialized. She is very comfortable with my wife (bonded), but I have stopped trying to interact with her in the house because it scares her, and instead, just give her space.

I can take her for a walk with or without my wife and she is fine. I can even carry her for blocks (outside) and she is very relaxed, but in the house she avoids me. She doesn't take treats yet, but we are working on that. We've only had her for six weeks, so she is very new to our world. We never yell or scold her. She is already house-trained and has her own "patch in the yard, so she learns very quickly. Her favorite place to be is in her crate or under my wife's desk.

I'm optimistic that she will accept me, but I feel that if I could understand what it is that is making her so nervous and apprehensive about me, that maybe I could modify my behavior to not "scare" her.

Comment: I assume she want to greet you, then pass you and go the whole stair, because she can not turn around on the "slippery" steps, and then follow you, whetever you go.

Comment: She does not want me to approach her and is very nervous when I get close to her, so I don't think  "greet" at least in the normal sense is what it is. The stairs aren't slippery, but thanks for the suggestions. I've started to wear light colored clothes and never approach her head on and also letting her see me pet other dogs. Too soon to tell. She has gone through so many changes in 6 weeks, and I expect more to come!